# Can I get the Unicode category of a codepoint in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

Swift has the [generalCategory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/properties/3081566-generalcategory) property on a Unicode scalar. Is this information also accessible from Objective C?

Comment: From my searching it is not, but it should be easy to write an @objc method which takes a string and returns the general categories of its scalars. You would just need to convert them to an Objective-C-compatible type. You could make a duplicate enum with int raw values (tedious to implement, but convenient to use) or convert the category to a string (easy to implement, less convenient to use).